# Align two columns next to each other without removing them from their container?

Tags: html, css, css-float

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="content">
   </div>
   <div class="sidebar">
   </div>
</div>
```

In the above example I can't seem to get content and sidebar to show up next to each other without using floats. Using floats works but it removes them from the bounds of the content class.

Comment: `display:inline-block` or `table-cell` could help. What your actual problem with float is, I'm not sure I understand - but floating the container as well or giving it `overflow:auto` will make it contain the floated child elements.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all of the really good answers, I chose Kilian's post as the answer because it's the one I ended up using. However all of the other answers were really good as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question right, the problem is not the `float` itstelf, but the missing clearing of the `floats`.

You can use `floats` and just add a clearfix to your `.container` class:

```
.container:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

This acts the same way as adding `<div style="clear: both"></div>` at the bottom html of `.container`

Comment: The problem I had with this was that with no other conent in the container the containers dimensions would be # x 0 when I wanted the content divs height to match it's content.

Comment: Hm, I tried this a few times and it never seemed to work correctly however using your code for reference I just tried it again and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/8nPWg/)***

What you are looking for is an inline-block

sample html

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="content">
 </div>
 <div class="sidebar">
 </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.content, .sidebar
{
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: But then using any `block` element inside them would be invalid, right?

Comment: @Sourabh - As a result of the "block" part of `inline-block` you may still use block elements in there.

Comment: Here's an example of the problem I was having. I found that it's because of white space from inline elements. http://jsfiddle.net/gRuAb/

Comment: @Renari - The line break you use will show up in an inline element. That is what causes the 2px wide gap there. Look at this updated version where there is no line break: http://jsfiddle.net/gRuAb/1/

Comment: Yeah that's how I fixed it, it just bugs me to format the html that way since it's less readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
.content{display:inline-block;}
.sidebar{display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this before but it seems the white space that inline elements have was forcing the element down where I didn't want it. I ended up making the HTML less readable but I fixed it by removing the white space between the elements.

Comment: @Renari - In that case, you need to set a `vertical-align` property.

Comment: That's not what I was referring to because of the extra white space the sidebar would not fit where it wanted it to since there was exactly enough space for it to fit there. With the extra white space there wasn't.

Comment: you can also use floating for this, but if you use floating then you have to add another div after the closing div of sidebar with style clear:both , because when we use float property in any dive we have to clear it to put the divs in their container for example 
<div>
    <div style="float:left">
    <div style="float:left">
    <div style="clear:both">
</div>